# How do I change the github repo my React app is connected to?

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I was trying to add my react project to github when I accidentally spelled my username wrong in the terminal. Now whenever I try to add the project to a repository it says it cannot find the repository, the one where I spelled my username wrong. How can I change which repository my project is being pushed into? I am new to using Git and Github.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change the remote URL of the local repo.

> git remote set-url <remote_name> <remote_url>

Example:

> git remote set-url origin https://git-repo/new-repository.git

More info on this can be found [here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-change-git-remote-origin/)

Other than that, I would recommend deleting your .git folder in the root of your project and start all over again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the GitHub repository if you only made a mistake in the username.

You need to drop the wrong authorization from credential helper.

```
  echo "url=https://github.com" | git credential reject
```

Then repeat `git push`. And don't forget that instead of a password you should enter your [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Answer (score 0):

If your app is connected to the wrong remote repo you can connect it again:

first check your remote:

```
git remote -v
```

The output will look something like this (`<shortname> <url>`), e.g.:

```
origin  https://github.com/user/repo_name.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo_name.git (push)
```

if that is the one with the wrong name in it you can remove that connection:

```
git remote rm <short-name>
```

Then you can add a new remote with the right spelling in it, e.g.:

```
git remote add origin <url>
```